# Trying implement CSS on href in div tag

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<div id="NAHC-topText">
<h2><a href="index.html">Link To Somewhere</a></h2>
</div>
```

I want to have CSS remove the underline and change the hover colour as the user rolls over the link. The link loads simple html.
I don't see to be able to implement this in the div tag successfully.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So just set the appropriate values in CSS.

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Depending on your actual need, you may want to change the selector to `#NAHC-topText a` instead of just `a`.

Comment: I think he wanted it underlined until its hovered over.

Answer (score 1):

In adittion to Sirko's answer , if you want to affect only

```
<a>
```

within Yours

```
<div id="NAHC-topText"> <h2>
```

Your stylesheet should look like this , in order to exclude any other anchors and headers.

```
#NAHC-topText h2 a {text-decoration:none;}
#NAHC-topText h2 a:hover {color:red;}
```

But of course there is nothing wrong with Sirko's answer , only it would affect all Your Anchors within the particular document.

Also if You want the underline only to display upon hover , you simply define

```
a {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;color:red;}
```

with the particular selector of Your choice

now that i red Your question again , this applies vice versa for the opposite situation
when You want it first underlined , and upon hover without underline , you simply swap the condition for each situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  #NAHC-topText a{text-decoration:none;}
  #NAHC-topText a:hover{color:red;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#NAHC-topText a:hover{
   color: red;
   text-decoration:none;
}
```